# Log4j disable logging for a class inside Spring.jar

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have an application using Spring, so I have spring.jar as a 3rd party library. 
I'm using log4j for logging and I've set the root level as INFO. Here is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource=WARN
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %m%n
```

As you can see, I've tried to set a specific class' (which is inside spring jar) logging level. However, it keeps logging as:

```
[1/7/14 11:53:35:150 EET] 0000003b ResourceBundl I org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource getTheme Theme created: name 'theme', basename [theme]
```

so it is creating unnecessary text data and exaggerating my log file.

As far as I can see, the log level is INFO inside ResourceBundleMessageSource class.

So, why it keeps logging even if I've set the level to WARN?

Thanks!

Comment: You have set the log leve for `ResourceBundleMessageSource` not for `ResourceBundleThemeSource`. Different classes.

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I've fixed the class name but still the problem exists. Thanks for the comment btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the log level for the wrong class.

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource=WARN
```

when it should be

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource=WARN
```

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. M.Deinum also told about it. I've fixed the class name but nothing changes. Still printing the same log over and over again.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ErcumentKisa hello, have you find  a solution ? i'm interested

Comment: Hey @Mercer, your application server's classloader mode is causing this issue. It must be set as "PARENT_LAST" to make your configurations apply. Check this for how you can change it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421916/how-to-set-java-class-loader-parent-last)