# How to change class loader policy programmatically?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ear

In Websphere 7, I'm developing an EAR application. I need to configure all the modules to be "PARENT_LAST" class loader policy.

Now, I'm configuring by logging into the WebSphere admin console and doing the configuration manually.

Is there any configuration such as `application.xml` that can do this class loading policy automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set java class loader PARENT\_LAST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421916/how-to-set-java-class-loader-parent-last)

Answer (score 1):

The classloader attributes for an EAR are stored in the deployment.xml file.  The following information center articles provide ways to change the classloader attributes via scripting or programming:

[Modifying WAR class loader mode using wsadmin scripting](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-mp&topic=txml_warclmode)

[Manipulating additional attributes for a deployed application](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-mp&topic=TjmxConfigAppdeploy)

Comment: Any generic way available irrespective of which server i am deploying..?

Comment: If the deployment.xml is not in the EAR, it will be created on deployment.  You can then export the ear from WebSphere after making changes to the classloader.  This exported ear will contain the modified deployment.xml which will be used on redeployment.

Exporting enterprise applications
http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=compass&product=was-nd-dist&topic=trun_app_distr