# Deployment issue while Spring Boot 2.1.3 WAR ON Websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere-8

I am trying to deploy a war files created using Spring Boot version 2.1.3.RELEASE on Websphere 8.5.5.13

I read some articles and found the Spring boot version 2.1.x is not supported in Websphere 8.5.5.13 but on Websphere 9.x

Although I found some work around and tried the same - UI version.

But I am getting below exception.

We have some MDB bean setup in our application. Looks like the modified configuration not able to initialize MDB bean successfully.

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

```
[3/23/19 11:59:10:004 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: EJB class com.kundan.hrms.employee.mdb.EmployeeCacheRefreshSubscriber must have a public constructor that takes no parameters : cddb-api-boot_war#cddb-api-boot.war#EmployeeCacheRefreshSubscriber
[3/23/19 11:59:10:004 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3434)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:750)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.MetaDataMgrImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(MetaDataMgrImpl.java:564)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:633)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1413)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2273)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:005 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1303)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor292.invoke(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:006 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:664)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:91)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:007 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:608)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:008 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1404)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:196)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:009 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:967)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:514)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:335)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:010 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:949)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:011 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: EJB class com.kundan.hrms.employee.mdb.EmployeeCacheRefreshSubscriber must have a public constructor that takes no parameters : cddb-api-boot_war#cddb-api-boot.war#EmployeeCacheRefreshSubscriber
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.EJBUtils.validateEjbClass(EJBUtils.java:375)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.JITDeploy.validateInterfaceBasics(JITDeploy.java:253)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.loadCustomerProvidedClasses(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:4243)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ejb.EJBMDOrchestrator.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(EJBMDOrchestrator.java:7868)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime.finishBMDInitForReferenceContext(AbstractEJBRuntime.java:1678)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.createNestedModuleMetaData(EJBContainerImpl.java:3427)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     ... 95 more
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/jms/JMSException, method=<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V, pc=0
[3/23/19 11:59:10:012 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:377)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:857)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:765)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:606)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:852)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:300)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:543)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.jitdeploy.EJBUtils.validateEjbClass(EJBUtils.java:365)
[3/23/19 11:59:10:013 EDT] 0000028a SystemErr     R     ... 100 more
```

Comment: Found below article as a workaround ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156126/websphere-8-5-with-spring-5

Comment: That seems to be just saying that you need a default constructor for class `com.kundan.hrms.employee.mdb.EmployeeCacheRefreshSubscriber`.